# calling methods from other classes

Tags: android, class, extends

hey i need some help with why i carnt call changeText() from ClassTwo
here is classOne

```
public class ClassOne extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ClassTwo classTwo = new ClassTwo();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        classTwo.changeText();

    }
}
```

and here is classTwo

```
public class ClassTwo extends ClassOne {    
    public void changeText(){
        TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    textOne.setText("this is how we call methods from other classes");
    }
}
```

the errors are at

```
com.game.ClassTwo.<init>(ClassTwo.java:5)
com.game.ClassTwo.<init>(ClassOne.java:10)
```

Comment: findViewById() will work only inside your activity class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while `ClassTwo` extends `ClassOne`, your instance `classTwo` is not initialized properly as an activity. It's not part of the view hierarchy so `findViewById` will not return anything. (You shouldn't create an instance of an Activity subclass by invoking `new` and expect any of the Android methods to do anything useful.)

Redesign your code so `ClassTwo` isn't an Activity subclass and redesign `changeText()` to accept an `Activity` instance as an argument. For instance:

```
package com.game;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class ClassTwo {
    public void changeText(ClassOne activity) {
        TextView textOne = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        textOne.setText("this is how we call methods from other classes");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but how do i call it in ClassOne? is it just calling changeText()?

Comment: As Adil said, just do ClassTwo.changeText(this);

Answer (score 0):

`ClassTwo` is a child of `ClassOne`. It is supposed to be the same kind of object. Default example would be furniture. You have a `Table` class (`classone`) and a `KitchenTable` class, that is a child of table obviously.

Now it is easy to see that a kitchentable can do the same stuff a table can do, but what you are trying to do is call kitchentable code inside of the table class. This is strange, because not all tables are in fact kitchentables. What if the table would be a camping-table?

SO back to the real world: If you want this structure, you should do all calling specific to things `classTwo` in classtwo self. If you don't then you might want something that is not releted in this extends way: remember, if you do `new ClassTwo`, you are making a new `activity`! This activity is points from classtwo to calssone, which has a classtwo, etc etc.

You probably need to redefine your class structure. Find out what you want, why you want it, etc.

Comment: well i have a textView with 5 buttons and i wanted to have a second class that runs all the text for the textView and buttons, or should i just have the code that runs all the text in the same class, so that findViewById works, which would be best practice

Comment: If it is a helper class it does not need to extend your first class.

Comment: Basically: don't use extend. But if you have to ask (and I'm not trying to be rude here), you might want to a) read up on OO // class structures or b) just make a member function in your first class.

Comment: i know some can be very rude, i go have a look

Answer (score 0):

Here's my problem with your code:

- ClassTwo extends ClassOne 
  [it shouldn't, especially if you are making an instance of ClassTwo in ClassOne]

To call a method from ClassOne, you would use the "super" keyword. For example,

```
 class ClassOne{
   public void myMethod() {
      // do stuff
   }
}

class ClassTwo extends ClassOne{
   @Override public void myMethod() {
      super.myMethod(); //call myMethod from ClassOne
      // add more stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: i just wanna know how to call methods from another class, anyone know how to?